# Custom TypeScript type of literal strings using union type does not equal string

Tags: typescript, union-types

I tried researching online, but I didn't find any solution to my problem. However, I've been awake for some time so that might be the reason that I didn't find it.

I have the following custom type

```js
export type gameDifficulty = 'easy' | 'normal' | 'hard' | 'extreme';
```

Which I use in the class Game

```js
export class Game {
   gameDifficulties: gameDifficulty[]
}
```

And I have an object (of a class) with difficulty of the same type

```js
export class Card {
   difficulty: gameDifficulty;
}
```

But whenever I try to loop my Card array  and check whether gameDifficulties has the difficulty of the card in its array, then it never equals true (example of how it looked in debugging below)

```js
cards.forEach(c => { // c.difficulty = 'easy' || c.difficulty = 'hard'
   if (gameDifficulties.includes(c.difficulty)) { // gameDifficulties = ['easy', 'hard']
       console.log(true) // I never enter here
   } else {
      console.log("Why am I false?")
   }
});
```

**What I tried**

Various test cases, playing around with the following things:

I checked types at runtime with `typeof()` and both outputed `string`.

I tried a testcase where I compared `Card.difficulty` to `easy` for example, but it also outputs as false.

(I even tried with `==` instead of `===` to see whether it still had to do with types, but didn't solve anything).

**What worked**

The only way I got it to work was by using `.startsWith()`, but this obviously doesn't solve or make me understand what went wrong.

**Something else I found out**

https://www.screencast.com/t/plV0hTc5OJ

The order in which you put `.startsWith()` matters although both are the same value (as in image of the link above).

**EDIT: added debugging session (0:29) below to clarify the issue**

I recorded my debugging session (0:29) so you can see where it goes wrong. [Debugging session](https://www.screencast.com/t/TepnCoJ3YWic)

**EDIT 2: added typescript version**

`"typescript": "~3.9.7"`

Comment: Did you check the contents of "c" in your cards.forEach and also your gameDifficulties array on run time to see if they do indeed match?

Comment: @DavidKo yes, I tried various test cases. cards always had values of multiple difficulties and gameDifficulties has `'normal'` by default but I also tested with other cases, no succes though. I suspect it has something to do with the custom type I created, but I don't know why.

Comment: Oh I just realized you don't want to define gameDifficulty as an interface it looks like your use case is just a type. 
export type gameDifficulty = 'easy' | 'normal' | 'hard' | 'extreme';

Does this fix it?

Comment: I agree with @DavidKo. Interface should be replaced with string literal type.

Comment: @DavidKo I'm not sure what you are suggesting? Replace my `type` with an interface and create 4 objects that implement the interface? That's seems like more work than it should be for such a simple problem.

Comment: @NikhilShekhar could you elaborate? I thought that my type was already a string literal type or a collection of string literal types (since I have multiple using the union type).

Comment: If you look at your first code example  you defined gameDifficulty as an interface when it should be type.  Not sure if its different in your actual code but that's what is written here.  I'm sure typescript would have pointed that out for you though.

Comment: @RubenSzekér Have a look at sample code below.

Comment: @DavidKo I'm sorry about that mistake. In my actual code it is in fact a `type`. I updated the code in the post. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting an interface, you could use an enum ([More information about enum here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)).
I think it is better suited for your needs.

**EDIT**

It is possible to use enum with string values (see [String enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums))

```js
enum GameDifficulty {
  easy = 'easy', normal = 'normal', hard = 'hard', extreme = 'extreme'
}
const gameDifficulties: GameDifficulty[] = [GameDifficulty.normal, GameDifficulty.hard];
const cards = [{difficulty:GameDifficulty.easy}, {difficulty:GameDifficulty.hard}];
cards.forEach(c => {
   if (gameDifficulties.includes(c.difficulty)) {
      console.log("found difficulty", c.difficulty);
   } else {
      console.log("difficulty not found?", c.difficulty)
   }
});
```

Here is the same example in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/johnedvard/pen/zYBmbye?editors=0011)

**Original**

enum, which will be converted to ints (see [Numeric enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums))

```js
enum GameDifficulty { // Common practice to make first letter to capitalLetter in enum.
  'easy', 'normal', 'hard', 'extreme'
}

const gameDifficulties: GameDifficulty[] = [GameDifficulty.normal, GameDifficulty.hard];
const cards = [{difficulty:GameDifficulty.easy}, {difficulty:GameDifficulty.hard}];
cards.forEach(c => {
   if (gameDifficulties.includes(c.difficulty)) {
      console.log("found difficulty", GameDifficulty[c.difficulty]);
   } else {
      console.log("difficulty not found?", GameDifficulty[c.difficulty])
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this is not fully what I'm looking for. I was quite aware when I chose for a `type` over an `enum`. In my personal experience I find it hard to work with enums because they get converted to `int`s over HTTP requests, which is quite unfriendly to work with when it comes to debugging, viewing data etc. That's why I chose a union type over an enum since it's typed, not an int and readable. It's also quite friendly to work with translations (in Angular) when using a type.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @RubenSzekér I added an other example to the answer, still using enum, but you can use String enum instead of Numeric enum. It may not be what you are looking for, but it is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code using string literal -

```
type gameDifficulty = 'easy' | 'normal' | 'hard' | 'extreme';

class Game {
  gameDifficulties: gameDifficulty[] = [];
}

class Card {
  difficulty: gameDifficulty = "easy";
}

const cards = Array<Card>();
  cards.push({ difficulty: "easy" });
  cards.push({ difficulty: "extreme" });

  let g = new Game();
  g.gameDifficulties = ["easy", "hard"];

  cards.forEach((c) => {
    if (g.gameDifficulties.includes(c.difficulty)) {
      // gameDifficulties = ['easy', 'hard']
      console.log(c);
      console.log(true); 
    } else {
      console.log(c);
      console.log(false); 
    }
  });
```

Try out this snippet [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA5ghgWwgEQJYDN2oMYFcA2oUAvFAOQRwDOIZUAPuQHYD2ATgnPnY2QBZw2AEx7kIAD2BsISMgG4AUNnzUqUAOKJoAbwVRYWtJhwFgqCFQBcBpEax5CIANoBdElFeKAvgqUqqagDCgkJQuvpCGPamINbwtlEmju4ARJQ0Kd6%202CxMVMBQ2CFqpACCbGxwIAA8wcIAfAAUAJSK%20kXCVAB0YLhUfI3aUJHGDqDWadQgKVBerXqFxT19A0Mj0Y4TElIyEDNzigv4EAUw7kwQAO4aWi1tsF3xKIlj5iUekxkANFApAsIpFyHdpLdDsACicGwA0a2GaJHqYQW%20gwUEaMEehhepjeXVQTGUuCEFlhXXWSVAzXh4X0tIA9HSbM9RjiLO4nBQpmQfvwQmQXMjaTk8ixjl18CwYLD5rShbkqKKIOLJY0pLgIK0oIKvFAIPgqDpBe15YrlVK4fdZcKFWKJVL0FwDZrtQsDkA)

Comment: I am confused why it works in the playground, but not in my application. I recorded my debugging session (0:29) so you can see where it goes wrong. [Debugging session](https://www.screencast.com/t/TepnCoJ3YWic). EDIT: posted new link since the screen of the previous link wasn't viewable